# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class org.academic.server.entities.StudentEntity (JPA)

Tags: java, object, jpa, server, casting

I'm trying to cast "Object" instances native query results of MySQL database to entity class. That is happening in "Server" application, after receiving request from "client" side.
Basically fragment of problematic code looks on that moment like this:

```
else if(operation == GET_STUDENT_SUBJECTS_DATA) {
                    System.out.println("I'm getting students subjects data!");
                    StudentSubjectRequestDto studentGradesRequestData = (StudentSubjectRequestDto) inStream.readObject();
                    Query queryForGettingStudent = databaseJpaHandler.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Students S WHERE S.Email = :email ")
                            .setParameter("email", studentGradesRequestData.getEmail());
                    List<StudentEntity> listOfStudentsMatched = (List<StudentEntity>)(List<?>) queryForGettingStudent.getResultList();
                    if(!listOfStudentsMatched.isEmpty()) {
                        StudentEntity student = listOfStudentsMatched.get(0);
                        Query queryForGettingStudentSubjects =  databaseJpaHandler.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT UD.Shortcut, Subj.Name, P.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName, SS.Grade, Subj.ECTS, Subj.Specification FROM StudentsSubjects SS INNER JOIN Students St on SS.StudentID = St.ID INNER JOIN Subjects Subj on SS.SubjectID = Subj.ID INNER JOIN University_Departments UD on St.DEPARTMENT_ID = UD.ID INNER JOIN Professors P on Subj.ProfessorID = P.ID " +
                                " WHERE St.Email := email")
                                .setParameter("email", student.getEmail());
                        if(sendStatusToClient(queryForGettingStudentSubjects, outStream, 10) > 0) {
                            List<StudentSubjectResponseDto> listOfStudentsResponse = queryForGettingStudentSubjects.getResultList();
                            outStream.writeObject(listOfStudentsResponse);
                        }


}
```

When there is match and "listOfStudentsMatched" isn't empty at the first instruction of if I'm getting exception with output:

```
NFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class org.academic.server.entities.StudentEntity ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.academic.server.entities.StudentEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
I'm getting students subjects data!
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM Students S WHERE S.Email = ? 
    at org.academic.server.Server.run(Server.java:160)
```

*StudentEntity.java*

```
package org.academic.server.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Students", schema = "academic_data")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Surname")
    private String surname;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Degree")
    private String degree;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Semester")
    private int semester;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PhoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String address;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private int departmentId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    private Set<SubjectEntity> subjects = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<SubjectEntity> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<SubjectEntity> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public int getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public void setSemester(int semester) {
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StudentEntity that = (StudentEntity) o;
        return id == that.id && semester == that.semester && departmentId == that.departmentId && Objects.equals(name, that.name) && Objects.equals(surname, that.surname) && Objects.equals(degree, that.degree) && Objects.equals(phoneNumber, that.phoneNumber) && Objects.equals(address, that.address) && Objects.equals(email, that.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, surname, degree, semester, phoneNumber, address, email, departmentId);
    }
}
```

What is the reason behind this exception?
From my understanding I'm getting list of objects, which could be converted to entity class. But it seems there is problem here.

EDIT
This is the problematic line, from which I'm getting above exception message:

```
StudentEntity student = listOfStudentsMatched.get(0);
```

Comment: If you tries a `TypedQuery<StudentEntity>`  instead of a `Query` only?

Comment: @Marc Le Bihan Could you past some example how it should look?
Currently for such code:
"                    TypedQuery<StudentEntity> queryForGettingStudent = databaseJpaHandler.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("SELECT * FROM Students S WHERE S.Email = :email ", StudentEntity.class)
                            .setParameter("email", studentGradesRequestData.getEmail());"
I'm getting such output:
"NativeQueryImpl cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.TypedQuery (org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl and javax.persistence.TypedQuery are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"

Comment: `TypedQuery<StudentEntity> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT u FROM StudentEntity u WHERE u.id=:id", StudentEntity.class);` or `createNamedQuery` shall also exist.

Comment: Your result is an array (that's what the `[` in front of `java.lang.Object` means) that you try to cast to a single `StudentEntity`. Which one is line 160?

Comment: That's probably from your `SELECT UD.Shortcut, Subj.Name, P.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName, SS.Grade, Subj.ECTS, Subj.Specification`. What is `StudentSubjectResponseDto`?

Comment: @Manfred I specified just now in question text above specific line from which I'm getting exception.
About "StudentSubjectResponseDto", it is from package "dto". It is basically data transfer object, send from server to client.

Comment: Aha, so `getResultList()` on `SELECT * FROM Students S` seems to return a `List<Object[]>` – `List` of all rows, and `Object[]` for the individual `*` fields. It seems that we can't expect the `Object[]` of fields to be automatically converted to a `StudentEntity`.
Unrelated to your problem, but to your question: Why do you include all the `if(!listOfStudentsMatched.isEmpty())` handling code from after the line that throws the exception? It should be irrelevant, right?